# How do I delete a line in a text file using python?

Tags: python, twitter

I have a corpus text file that is fed into a twitter app that periodically tweets one line at a time. However, after tweeting a line, I would like for it to delete it from the text file. Here is the current code that tweets out the lines (I did not originally write this code, but I have modified it slightly):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# by robincamille - for mechnicalpoe

# Tweets a .txt file line by line, waiting an hour between each tweet.
# Must be running all the time, e.g. on a Raspberry Pi, but would be better
# if rewritten to run as a cron task.

import tweepy, time
import random

filename=open('lines.txt','r')
f=filename.readlines()
filename.close()

#f = random.choice(open('lines.txt').readlines())

for line in f:

     api.update_status(line)
     print line
     time.sleep(160) # Sleep
```

How could I modify it to make it delete each line immediately after tweeting it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't delete any line from a file :)

Just read the file into a list and tweet (and remove) an element of the list.

And: you don't wait "an hour" (as stated by the comment) - it's 160 seconds!

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably start by reading the whole file in, tweet and delete the line that you want, and print out the file again.

Check your time for sleeping an hour.  3600 seconds are in an hour.

As the comment suggested cron may be better. I would make a program that just does this for one tweet and put the program into cron.  This way you don't have a lingering python process.

This runs once per hour:
0 * * * * (/path/to/program; python program.py arg)

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/
http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml